# How to calculate the distance between two addresses

Tags: php, api, openstreetmap, street-address

I would like to calculate the distance between two points. The points are addresses.

Example:

Point A: *JFK Airport, New York, NY, United States*

Point B: *La Guardia, New York, NY, United States*

Now I want to calculate the distance (via roads) and the travel time between point A and point B.

How can I do that? Is it possible to use google maps API? How would you approach the problem?

Answer (score 20):

```
<?php 
$from = "sr nagar,hyderabad";
$to = "kukatpalle,hyderabad";
$from = urlencode($from);
$to = urlencode($to);
$apiKey= "";  
$data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$from&destinations=$to&key=$apiKey&language=en-EN&sensor=false");
$data = json_decode($data);
$time = 0;
$distance = 0;
foreach($data->rows[0]->elements as $road) {
    $time += $road->duration->value;
    $distance += $road->distance->value;
}
echo "To: ".$data->destination_addresses[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo "From: ".$data->origin_addresses[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo "Time: ".$time." seconds";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Distance: ".$distance." meters";
?>
```

Note : above you need to km and time h:m format just replace with

```
$time      = $road->duration->text;
$distance  = $road->distance->text;
```

Comment: @RajaRamaMohanThavalam You should state the request LIMIT of the given google map api

Comment: Keyless access to the Google maps API is now deprecated, so this will no longer work.

Comment: You will need to generate a Google maps API key and add "&key=yourkeygoeshere" to the end of the URL for the above code to work.  Use this link to create your API Key:  http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Maps API and PHP for calculates the distance between two address.

```
$addressFrom = 'Insert from address';
$addressTo = 'Insert to address';
$distance = getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, "K");
echo $distance;
```

getDistance() function can be found from here - http://www.codexworld.com/distance-between-two-addresses-google-maps-api-php/